# Ontology with concepts about many domains (transport, environment, engineering, …)

Tags: ontology

I am looking for an ontology or a controlled vocabulary which contains concepts about many domains such as transport, environment, engineering.

Is there such a vocabulary available?

Comment: I'd recommend that you look at library filing systems.  (Universal Decimal Classification, Dewey Decimal System, Library of Congress Subject Headings, etc.)

Comment: Look at this [question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11401/16193).

Answer (score 3):

There are several "common" ontologies published for Open Data. Here are some:

Linked Open Vocabulary (LOV): http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/

Linked Open Data (LOD) : http://linkeddata.org/

We (OpenGeoCode) have our own published ontology:

Vocabulary: http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.2/LinkedCSV-Vocab.php
Specification: http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.2/csv1.2.php

Answer (score 3):

The [open directory project **DMOZ**](http://www.dmoz.org) is probably too shallow for scientific use, but maybe appropriate to get a "average Joe" perspective on concepts visible in such topics as

- Science/[Environment](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Environment/)
- Science/Technology/[Transportation](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Technology/Transportation/)

Another more extensive, but messier and more involved procedure to look into the structure of **Wikipedia categories**. Here is an [example tree for *Environment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ACategoryTree&target=Environment&mode=categories&namespaces=). Problem: [they are chaos](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T3497).

Comment: The hierarchy is interesting, do they have an ontology for describing this hierarchy ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at Adam Pease's [SUMO](http://www.adampease.org/OP/) (Suggested Upper Merged Ontology) which is quite broad and covers those knowledge domains.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6277/ontology-with-concepts-about-many-domains-transport-environment-engineering#comment14753_6277