# Ontological Database of Objects

Tags: data-request, database, ontology

I am searching for a Database containing a hierarchical Ontology of most objects.

For example, an Apple is a special type of an edible Fruit, which is a special type of Fruit. A Fruit is a physical Object and therefore has a volume, weight, smell etc.

I have found some openly available Ontological Databases, like [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple), but extracting the hierarchical Information is non-trivial.

Has anyone worked with similar Databases and is able to recommend something similar?

Comment: "extracting the hierarchical Information is non-trivial"-- I think you're going to run into this issue with any ontology. Having said that, see if you can find data in RDF triples format, which is probably the simplest it's going to get.

Comment: building off @BarryCarter's comment here, you should certainly check out wikidata, datasets that wikipedia are using.

Comment: Although you already selected an answer, what do you want to use this data for? Better answers might still be possible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...but extracting the hierarchical information is non-trivial.

- DBpedia T-Box dump is available to download as a separate file from [this
  page](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/services-resources/ontology).
- Wikidata classes and properties dumps are available to download as separate files from [this
  page](http://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-exports/rdf/exports/20160801/dump_download.html).

> I am searching for a database containing a hierarchical ontology of
>   most objects.

Many of the so-called *upper ontologies* are in fact very comprehensive or have many domain-specific extensions:

- [YAGO](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/downloads/) (look at TAXONOMY and SIMPLETAX "themes")
- [SUMO](http://www.adampease.org/OP/)
- [UMBEL](http://umbel.org/)
- [DOLCE](http://www.loa.istc.cnr.it/old/DOLCE.html)

There are also the so-called *commonsense knowledge bases*:

- [Cyc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc)
- [ConceptNet](http://conceptnet.io/)
- [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)

Many of these ontologies and commonsense knowledge bases are interlinked.

Comment: The commonsense bases seem very interesting and there are some awesome tools building upon them. Thanks!