# How to build a concept hierarchy using LOD?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, research, linked-data, rdf, ontology

I am interested in building a concept hierarchy using the given Computer Science related concepts. For an example we can consider 'support vector machine', whether the parent category would be 'machine learning', the parent category of 'machine learning' could be 'artificial intelligence' etc.

Being a novice in this field, I am interested in getting some expert recommendations about the resources I can use for this in LOD? Can we only use DBpedia for this, Or are there any other resources that I can try out?

I am happy to provide more examples if needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible answers were listed in your previous questions.

Perhaps some [upper ontologies](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11396/ontological-database-of-objects/11401#11401) contain what you need.

Another possible source is Wikidata. For example, [this](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q282453) is SVM's page on Wikidata. As you can see, the `wdt:P279` ("subclass of") predicate currently corresponds to the parent-child relation you are talking about.

The query below lists all parent-child relation between descendants of `wd:Q11660` ("artificial intelligence").

```
#defaultView:Graph
SELECT DISTINCT ?s1 ?s1Label ?s2 ?s2Label WHERE {
    VALUES (?s3) {(wd:Q11660)}
    ?s0 wdt:P279* ?s1 .  ?s1 wdt:P279 ?s2 . ?s2 wdt:P279* ?s3 .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23defaultView%3AGraph%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs1%20%3Fs1Label%20%3Fs2%20%3Fs2Label%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fs3%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ11660%29%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs0%20wdt%3AP279%2a%20%3Fs1%20.%20%20%3Fs1%20wdt%3AP279%20%3Fs2%20.%20%3Fs2%20wdt%3AP279%2a%20%3Fs3%20.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D)

You could also be interested in [this simple tool](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikidata-todo/tree.html?q=11660&rp=279&method=list&depth=4).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great great answer. Now I am in a situation to select DBpedia, YAGO and Wikidata, which seems to be not very easy for me. By looking at the advantages and disadvantages can you please recommend me the most suitable resource that I should use? :)

Comment: Well, compare the tree from the answer with [this one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CategoryTree?target=Category%3AArtificial+intelligence&mode=categories&namespaces=&title=Special%3ACategoryTree).

Comment: Thank you very much. Are both of trees made from wikidata?

Comment: @JCena, the tree from my previous comment is from Wikipedia. DBpedia reflects Wikipedia categories structure.