# Publicly available example ontologies for financial and political domain

Tags: data-request, ontology

I'm doing a research project and I have trouble finding suitable ontologies for financial and political domains. Political domain means any kind of political ontology regarding any country. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check [large ontologies](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11401/16193) and their fragments. Check Financial Industry Business Ontology (FIBO) for financial domain. Search particular  terms on https://lov.okfn.org/ (currently is down).